# Azure Full Screen URL Dashboard

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'd like to put some Azure portal dashboards into Rotisserie which works, but I'd like to get the URL to full screen the Azure dashboards by default.

If you log into the Azure management portal at portal.azure.com, click Dashboard, and then click the Full Screen button you'll see a nice full screen dashboard. I have a few of these to rotate through and while I can use the direct URL to do so, it is not in full screen mode. I'm hoping there's a URL for direct access to the full screen mode for these dashboards.

I haven't been able to find any magic URL yet, and I'm hoping its something simple like adding ?kiosk=true or ?chromeless=1 to the end of the URL for the dashboard.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking about? What Azure Dashboard are you referring to? What is "Rotisserie" and how does this relate to your issue? As is, this isn't a programming question, as well as being unclear. Please edit to include more specifics, code, etc. Also: Please don't include irrelevant tags - I removed them.

Comment: As David highlighted you have to provide more details to help guide you in the right direction. Help us help you. 
Are you referring to opening the Azure Portal maximized?  
Are you referring dashboard in the Azure Portal as mentioned in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards?

Comment: Hi David and Ajay,  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I am referring to Azure Portal Dashboards as David pointed out.  If you log into the Azure management portal at https://portal.azure.com, click Dashboard, and then click the Full Screen button you'll see a nice full screen dashboard.  I have a few of these to rotate through and while I can use the direct URL to do so, it is not in full screen mode.  I'm hoping there's a URL for direct access to the full screen mode for these dashboards.

Answer (score 2):

found 2 solutions:

1. for a dashboard, just add '/embed' at the end
2. for queries, just use '?fullScreen=true'

regards

Comment: The ?fullScreen=true works! thanks

Comment: I wasn't able to get the first solution to function, but adding `?fullScreen=true` worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing feature request for this functionality.  If you think this would be useful please take the time to vote on it:

Fullscreen query string Option: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/31757251-fullscreen-query-string-option

Answer (score 0):

This is Adam Abdelhamed from the Azure portal team. We don't currently support this. It's a good idea though.